# Scala Akka router configuration not found in configuration file when it's really there

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I would be grateful for some help with this Akka configuration question.  This is probably something obvious, but I've been googling and looking at it all morning and have not yet come up with an answer.

My `ActorSystem` is created thus:

```
val config = ConfigFactory.load("akka.conf")
implicit val system = ActorSystem("fubar", config)
```

The classloader sees my configuration file since changes to logging levels take effect.

After creating the `ActorSystem`, my code does the following:

```
val mpr = system.actorOf(Props[ProcessingFlow])
```

In the `ProcessingFlow` the following:

```
val actorSink: Sink[PackedRecord, ActorRef] = Sink.actorSubscriber(Props[RCStreamReceiver])
```

In `RCStreamReceiver` the following:

```
 val logWorkers = context.actorOf(FromConfig.props(Props[LogWorker]), "logWorker")
```

Yet, I get the following:

```
Configuration missing for router [akka://fubar/user/$a/StreamSupervisor-0/flow-3-2-actorSubscriberSink/logWorker] in 'akka.actor.deployment' section.
```

This in spite of my config file looking like this:

```
akka {
  loggers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"]
  loglevel = "WARNING"
  logging-filter = "akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLoggingFilter"
  logger-startup-timeout = 15s
  actor {
    provider = "akka.cluster.ClusterActorRefProvider"
    debug {
      log-config-on-start = off
      autoreceive = off
      lifecycle = off
      unhandled = on
      event-stream = off
    }
    deployment {
      default-dispatcher {
        fork-join-executor {
          parallelism-min = 8
        }
      }
      /"*"/logWorker = {
        router = balancing-pool
        nr-of-instances = 5
        executor = "thread-pool-executor"
        thread-pool-executor {
          core-pool-size-min = 5
          core-pool-size-max = 5
        }

      }

      /"*"/editWorker = {
        router = balancing-pool
        nr-of-instances = 5
        routees.paths = ["/foo/editWorker"]
      }

      /"*"/unknownWorker = {
        router = balancing-pool
        nr-of-instances = 5
        routees.paths = ["/foo/unknownWorker"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: try to put log-workers configuration directly under Akka and not under the deployment

Comment: Same result: `Configuration missing for router [akka://fubar/user/$a/StreamSupervisor-0/flow-4-2-actorSubscriberSink/logWorker] in 'akka.actor.deployment' section.`

Comment: Can you try changing `/"*"/logWorker` for `"/**/logWorker"`?

Comment: Thanks.  Same result: `Caused by: akka.ConfigurationException: Configuration missing for router [akka://fubar/user/$a/StreamSupervisor-0/flow-3-1-actorSubscriberSink/logWorker] in 'akka.actor.deployment' section.`

Comment: I've checked that when `RCStreamReceiver` starts, it is indeed using the "fubar" `ActorSystem` with the configuration in it.